# psql return code if zero rows found

Tags: linux, bash, postgresql, psql

I would like for my psql command to fail if zero rows are found:

```
psql -U postgres -d db -c "select * from user where id=1 and name='Joe';"
```

I want to be able to check the return value. Return 0 from the process(!) if at least one row exists and return non-zero from the psql process if no such row exists. How can I set a return code if no rows are found?

Comment: why not try `select count(*)`. A lot cheaper, too.

Comment: @Dinesh `select count(*)` will always return a row.

Comment: @eatonphil Please look to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30027767/1216680) it may be what you're looking for whithout using the `grep` command

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I don't think psql can do it by itself, but if you just want to see if there are any rows or not with the exit status you could combine it like

```
psql -U postgres -d db -t -c "select * from user where id=1 and name='Joe'" | egrep .
```

That will cause egrep to exit with non-zero if it cannot match anything.  The `-t` will make it not print the column headers and summary information, so you may need to tweak this command line if you need that stuff.