# Check if one request fails with the command-line

Tags: postgresql, shell, command-line

I have those two requests in one file :

```
select id from "user" where id = 1; // request passes
select from "user"; // request fails
```

When I run the following commands in my shell :

```
psql -U username -d db_name -h host -p port -f test.sql
echo $?
```

This will always prompt me **0** (assuming that the credentials are correct, and the `psql`  command ran without execution error). This seems pretty fair.

I was wondering if there was any way to get a different return code if one of the queries inside the linked file fails ?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On the first line of the script, add `\set ON_ERROR_STOP on` . psql will return exit code 3 when the script failed.

Comment: You rock buddy ! Thanks for the tip !