# Bash purge script

Tags: sql, bash, postgresql, psql

I'm trying to create a script that removes my images that are not in DB

There is my code (Updated): 
I have 1 problems:

- Problem with the like syntax  `like '%$f%'`

```bash
#!/bin/bash

db="intranet_carc_development"
user="benjamin"

for f in public/uploads/files/*
do
  if [[ -f "$f" ]]
  then
    psql $db $user -t -v "ON_ERROR_STOP=1" \
    -c 'select * from public.articles where content like "%'"$(basename "$f")"'%"' | grep . \
    && echo "exist" \
    || echo "doesn't exist"
  fi
done
```

And I have the following error :

```
ERROR:  column "%1YOLV3M4-VFb2Hydb0VFMw.png%" does not exist
LINE 1: select * from public.articles where content like "%1YOLV3M4-...
                                                         ^
doesn't exist
ERROR:  column "%wnj8EEd8wuJp4TdUwqrJtA.png%" does not exist
LINE 1: select * from public.articles where content like "%wnj8EEd8w...
```

EDIT : if i use `\'%$f%\'` for the `like` :

```
/purge_files.sh: line 12: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"'
./purge_files.sh: line 16: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

Comment: [Don't parse 'ls'](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs). You don't even need the `tab2` variable. Try `for f in public/uploads/files/*; do ...`.

Comment: Code updated @Aserre

Comment: for `FILENAME`: `basename /path/to/FILENAME`

Comment: ha you one exemple , @Arount ? don't really understand how to do

Comment: append a line before `if test -f "$f"` like `f="$(basename "$f")"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several issues with your code :

- **$f is public/uploads/files/FILENAME and i want only the FILENAME**

You can use `basename` to circumvent that, by writing :

```
f="$(basename "$f")"
psql $db $user -c "select * from public.articles where content like '%$f%'"...
```

(The extra quotes are here to prevent issues if you have spaces and special characters in your file name)

- **your psql request will always return true [even if no rows are found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29948334/psql-return-code-if-zero-rows-found)**
- **your psql command will return true even if the request fails, unless you [set the variable 'ON_ERROR_STOP' to 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37072245/check-return-status-of-psql-command-in-unix-shell-scripting)**

As shown in the linked questions, you can use the following syntax :

```
#!/bin/bash

set -o pipefail #needed because of the pipe to grep later on

db="intranet_carc_development"
user="benjamin"

for f in public/uploads/files/*
do
  if [[ -f "$f" ]]
  then
    f="$(basename "$f")"
    psql $db $user -t -v "ON_ERROR_STOP=1" \
    -c "select * from public.articles where content like '%$f%'" | grep . \
    && echo "exist" \
    || echo "doesn't exist"
  fi
done
```

Comment: Post updated , Thanks , the first problem is solved but i have the same problem for the Like syntax :  i want something like :   'select ...... like '% $(basename)%' '

Comment: @BenjaminBarbé Updated, I think psql didn't like the double quotes. I simplified the syntax a bit.

Comment: Thanks !
it's up to me now to finish correctly but I'm in the right direction